# turn off battery diconnect whileunder load

Tags: battery

If I turn off my battery disconnect while under load will it work such as my starter on my motorcycle is push button direct hook up no relay , if I disconnect my switch will it let go or ark out and get real hot.

Comment: This is if my starter will not stop current will not let go and keeps on turning starter

Comment: Will what work if you turn off your battery disconnect? If the engine is running then don't do it, if not then nothing will work as you have disconnected the battery.

Comment: I just want to make sure I understand your question... Your starter-motor does not stop running? And you are wondering if disconnecting your battery will stop the starter-motor? **Do not disconnect the battery when your motorcycle is running.**